# where do you save custom saved strategies in factory girl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, factory-bot

I am trying to implement the new `FactoryGirl` custom build strategy from the `FactoryGirl` getting started guide.  I want to use the code they have to be able to output my factories as a `JSON` file.

They offered this code to output in `JSON`:

```
class JsonStrategy
  def initialize
    @strategy = FactoryGirl.strategy_by_name(:create).new
  end

  delegate :association, to: :@strategy

  def result(evaluation)
    @strategy.result(evaluation).to_json
  end
end
```

What directory should I save this code in order to use it within `FactoryGirl`?

here is the link to where I am getting the code and a further explanation of its functionality:

http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/21719164760/factorygirl-3-2-so-awesome-it-needs-to-be-released

Look under the header `"REGISTER CUSTOM BUILD STRATEGIES"`  about `2/3` down the page.

Answer (score 3):

I have my custom strategy saved in spec/support/custom_strategies.rb

```
#spec/support/custom_strategies.rb  
class JsonStrategy                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  def initialize                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    @strategy = FactoryGirl.strategy_by_name(:create).new                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  end                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         

  delegate :association, to: :@strategy                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

  def result(evaluation)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    @strategy.result(evaluation).to_json                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  end                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
end    

class SecondCustomStrategy
end
```

Or, you could create a directory in spec/support for custom_strategies if you want to separate them out. I register the custom strategy in spec/spec_helper.rb

```
#spec/spec_helper.rb
  RSpec.configure do |config|
    ##some code

    config.order = "random"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

    config.filter_run_excluding :broken => true                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

    config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  end                                 

  #registered after the Rspec.configure block                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  FactoryGirl.register_strategy(:json, JsonStrategy)                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

  require 'capybara/poltergeist'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
```

Comment: this is the way to go I think, and I agree it makes more sense to put it in spec/ and not lib/.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this issue myself and have been searching on where to save new strategies.

I can't seem to find a place where they are automatically loaded/included, but you can save the file wherever you like. I saved mine in lib/factory_girl/strategy/json.rb (this follows the same convention that they are saved in the factory girl repo).

Once saved, you will need to register your new strategy as described in the guide. If your strategy is not in your load path (mine is not), then you will need to require it before registering it.

This is the code I have in my spec_helper.rb file in order to require and then register the strategy

```
require "#{Rails.root}/lib/factory_girl/strategy/json"
FactoryGirl.register_strategy(:json, JsonStrategy)
```

After that, use is just as described in their guide and you should be good to go.